# Convert mimeType: from application/octate-stream to text/csv - Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to fetch a csv file attachment (msg_att) from an email, get the data and then copy it to a spreadsheet file. I am working on google scripts.
What I have done so far is the following:

```
  var newFile=DriveApp.createFile(msg_att).setName("GDriveData")
  var attachmentID = newFile.getId()
  var date = new Date();
  var files = DriveApp.getFileById(attachmentID)
  var xlsFile = files.getMimeType();  
  Logger.log(xlsFile);
  var newSheet =  Drive.Files.copy({}, attachmentID, {convert: true});
```

Unfortunately the last line returns the following error:

API call to drive.files.copy failed with error: The requested conversion is not supported

and the MimeType is **application/octate-stream**.

I investigated the issue and I saw that the mimeType should be "text/csv" since I want to fetch a csv attachment.

Is there any way to convert the mimeType: from application/octate-stream to text/csv ?

I tried this but it does not work:

```
 var newFile=DriveApp.createFile(msg_att).setName("GDriveData").setMimeType('text/csv')
```

I also tried this and it didn't work:

```
var newFile = DriveApp.createFile('name',msg_att,'text/csv');
```

Comment: When `Logger.log(msg_att.getDataAsString())` and `Logger.log(newFile.getBlob().getDataAsString())` are put after the line of `var newFile=DriveApp.createFile(msg_att).setName("GDriveData")` and run the script, what values will you see in the log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `msg_att` is actually a CSV, you can set the MIME type in `createFile()`: [`createFile(name, content, mimeType)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createFile(String,String,String))

Comment: Can you provide some details about how `msg_att` is defined/fetched?

Comment: I have a feeling the issue might be the file itself then. I just did a test with a version of your code and got 'text/csv' when I logged the MIME type. Can you confirm the file is indeed a CSV, and not a .xls file or something similar?